# Можно ли отсортировать список в порядке: 1. Цифры 2. Русский алфавит 3. Английский алфавит

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Требуется отсортировать большой список в следующем порядке:

1. Цифры
2. Русский алфавит
3. Английский алфавит.

Пример кода:

```
a = ["123", "АБВ", "ABC"]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Что получается:

```
>>>["123", "ABC", "АБВ"]
```

Что требуется:

```
>>>["123", "АБВ", "ABC"]
```

В документации, к сожалению, необходимой информации не удалось найти.

Comment: А sort может использовать функцию сравнения?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) параметр `key` принимает ссылку на функцию, которая будет использоваться при сортировке.

В `get_priority` определяем символ какой группы присутствует в строке и возвращаем приоритет для сортировки. Причем, для кириллицы нельзя просто в диапазоне указать `а-я`, т.к. `ё` не входит в диапазон, поэтому `а-яё`

Код:

```
import re

def get_priority(text: str) -> (int, str):
    if re.search('[0-9]', text):
        return 1, text

    if re.search('[а-яё]', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return 2, text

    if re.search('[a-z]', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return 3, text


a = ["123", "АБВ", "456", "ABC", "Кошка"]
a.sort(key=get_priority)
print(a)  # ['123', '456', 'АБВ', 'Кошка', 'ABC']
```

Comment: Чтобы сортировка работала в пределах одной группы (например отсортировать кириллические строки) надо возвращать кортеж: `1, text`, `2, text`, `3, text`... Для теста попробуйте отсортировать `a = ["Кошка", "123", "АБВ", "456", "ABC"]`

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, думал об этом :)